# Por que muestra Create pull request al regresar en algunas ramas

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

Estoy probando **GitHub Descktop**

- Cree un proyecto desde mi computadora a **modo de prueba**
- Realice un `git init` en el proyecto
- Despues con **Github Descktop** lo subi a **Github**
- Cree una rama o `branch` llamada **newBranch**
- Realice barios `commit` en **newBranch**
- Realice un `push origin`
- Me regrese a `master` realice un `merge` para lo cual seleccione la rama **newBranch** que es la que se incorpora a `master`, hasta ahi todo normal..
  al dar un `Push origin` estando en la rama `master`

Me muestra el siguiente mensaje **Create Pull Resquest**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si no mal entiendo eso es cuando se realiza una colaboración a un proyecto, pero en mi caso yo soy el creador del proyecto, por lo tanto estoy algo confundido o no entendi muy bien el funcionamiento de las **ramas**  en **git**

En la pagina la hacer `git push` muestra lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si haces `git remote -v` podrás ver la URL a la que intentará hacer el push. Verifica que es la URL de tu repositorio en github y no otro. Sólo puedes hacer push a un remoto sobre el que tengas permiso de escritura.

Comment: Me regresa lo siguiente lo cual es mi repositorio `origin  https://github.com/EvyiLdaRkmaN/version_1.git (fetch)`
`origin  https://github.com/EvyiLdaRkmaN/version_1.git (push)`

Comment: @abulafia se supone que al ser yo el dueño tengo todos los permisos o no ?

Comment: Sí, en principio así debería ser. ¿Puedes editar la pregunta y pegar en ella la respuesta completa que te da `git` ante el `push`?

Comment: he modificado la respuesta e ingrese una imagen ya que aparece en la interfaz de Github descktop

Comment: Según el mensaje, estás en la rama actualizaciones y no en master, ni en newBranch. Puede que eso tenga algo que ver. Igual está usando un repositorio diferente del que piensas. Has probado a hacer el `git push` desde línea de comandos?

Comment: @abulafia perdon agregue la imagen de el otro repositorio donde aparece pero ahi aparece en la rama que cree que se llama Actualizaciones ahora mismo ya edite la pregunta y agregue la que es donde estaba realizando las pruebas

Comment: desde la consola de comando haciendo `git push` parece que todo va perfecto y revisando si ya esta en **Github.com** parece que si se subieron los cambios pero me muestra un mensaje similar en la pagina.. ahora mismo agrego la imagen con lo que muestra la pagina

Comment: @abulafia muestra casi lo mismo que en la app, que es hacer el ``pull request`

Comment: Bueno, entonces es que el repositorio en cuestión no lo habías creado "desde cero", sino que era un _fork_ de otro repositorio. En ese caso te está invitando a que, si quieres, le hagas un _pull request_ al autor del repositorio original, que consiste en que él pueda ver los cambios que has hecho en esa rama y si le parecen bien pueda mezclarlos con los de su propio repositorio.

Comment: Entonces si yo le doy `git init` realizo el primer `commit` para subir después al repositorio no se considera original desde ahí ?

Comment: @abulafia lo que tendría que hacer es crear el repositorio primero en **Github** para despues clonarlo en mi maquina y de igual manera crear las ramas en **Github** ?